# GoTo specified line number using JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextpane

I want to place the cursor to user given line number.For this I had write code.But,when I enter a line number 2 the cursor was placed in after first character not in start of the second line.Please help me...Thank you.
Here is code:

```
public class GoToAction extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int i=0;
    JTextPane textPane;
    int lineCount;

    public GoToAction() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        file = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        goTo = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        file.setText("File");

        create.setText("Create");
        create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        file.add(create);

        goTo.setText("GoTo");
        goTo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                goToActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        file.add(goTo);

        jMenuBar1.add(file);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
        internalFrame.setClosable(true);
        internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        textPane=new JTextPane();
        textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
        internalFrame.add(textPane);
        tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }                                      

    private void goToActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
           do {
          try {
          String str = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Line number:\t","Goto line",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,null,null);
          if( str == null ) {
          break;
          }
          int lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(str);
          lineCount=getLineCount();
          if ( lineNumber > lineCount ) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Line number out of range","EPAD Goto line",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          continue;
          }   
          for ( int i = 0 ; i < lineCount; i++ ){
          if ( i+1 == lineNumber ) {
              textPane.setCaretPosition(i);
                      return;
          }
          }
          } catch ( Exception e ) {
          }
         } while ( true );
    }                                    
    public int getLineCount(){ 
        lineCount=0;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(textPane.getText());
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine(); 
            lineCount++;
       }
        return lineCount;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GoToAction().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem create;
    private javax.swing.JMenu file;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem goTo;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: view to model returns this coordinates

Comment: @mKorbel Answer, answer, answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `gotoStartOfLine(...)` method in [Text Utilities](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) for a more efficient solution that takes advantage of the `Element` structure of the `Document` used by the text component.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new method `public int setcursor(int newlineno)` and modified your code. 
In this method I am simply calculating your expected cursor position.

Run the below code ;)

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class GoToAction extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int i = 0;
    JTextPane textPane;
    int lineCount;

    public GoToAction() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        file = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        goTo = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        file.setText("File");
        create.setText("Create");
        create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        file.add(create);
        goTo.setText("GoTo");
        goTo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                goToActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        file.add(goTo);
        jMenuBar1.add(file);
        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(tabbedPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Document" + i);
        internalFrame.setClosable(true);
        internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
        internalFrame.add(textPane);
        tabbedPane.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void goToActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        do {
            try {
                String str = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, 
                        "Line number:\t", "Goto line", 
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (str == null) {
                    break;
                }
                int lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(str);
                lineCount = getLineCount();
                System.out.println(lineCount);
                if (lineNumber > lineCount) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
                            "Line number out of range", "EPAD Goto line", 
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    continue;
                }
                //  for ( int i = 0 ; i < lineCount; i++ ){
                //  if ( i+1 == lineNumber ) {
                //Rectangle rectangle = textPane.modelToView(textPane.getCaretPosition());
                textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
                System.out.println(setcursor(lineNumber));
                textPane.setCaretPosition(setcursor(lineNumber));
                return;
                //  }
                //  }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public int getLineCount() {
        lineCount = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(textPane.getText());
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            lineCount++;
        }
        return lineCount;
    }

    public int setcursor(int newlineno) {
        int pos = 0;
        int i = 0;
        String line = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(textPane.getText());
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            i++;
            if (newlineno > i) {
                pos = pos + line.length() + 1;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : 
                    javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GoToAction.class.getName())
                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GoToAction().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem create;
    private javax.swing.JMenu file;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem goTo;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    // End of variables declaration  
}
```

Comment: @user3709795, Not the most efficient solution since it does not take advantage of  the Element structure of the Document. First the getText() method needs to iterate through the Element structure of the Document to create a String. Then you need to parse the string and break it back into individual lines of text. Becomes more inefficient as more lines are added to the Document.

Comment: @camickr I know my solution is not very efficient, but I never used Text Utilities suggested by you. Good thing to learn. :)  +1 to your answer for showing it.